# Is there a way to reload form post variables in Chrome using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Although it's not ideal, the current legacy system has confined me to refreshing search results from a form post (method='POST'). This works fine in Firefox and in IE, but not in Chrome.

Is there a programmatic way (in javascript) to reload a page in Chrome, and reload the POST variables from the form submission?

Different versions of  `(location,reload(), location.reload(true), etc)` didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "reload the POST variables"?

Comment: You may be able to attach an event to the window's onbeforeunload event. In that, I'd imagine you could grab the form's datafields and save them using a cookie or localStorage or webSql. I don't know from experience, though I suspect this event will be called after the form submit button is pressed, but before any of the DOM is removed.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. By "reload" I mean refreshing the Search Results page using location.reload(). In Firefox or IE, it reloads the page again, including all POST data. Not so in Chrome. Did that answer the question?

Comment: enhzflep, that's an intriguing approach, perhaps using localStorage. It merits some consideration.